# .cu file Makefile issue

Tags: makefile, cuda

I am new to linux development.
I wrote a project using MPI and cuda. When
it gets bigger and bigger, I realize that I
need a Makefile now. So I learned how to write
one. The Makefile works, but will only compile
cpp files even if I have both of the following
lines in my Makefile:

.cpp.o:

```
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $<
```

.cu.o:

```
    $(NVCC) $(CCFLAGS) $<
```

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UNDERSTANDING MAKE

Make is all about generating missing files.

If you have TWO rules that generate the SAME file upon existence of a source then the first one in make's list that actually has a source file present will get invoked.  So for instance if you have the rules:

```
.c.o: 
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $<

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) -o $@ -c $<
```

and you have two files, foo.c and bar.cpp then you can type:

```
  $ make foo.o
```

it will use the first rule... and when you type

```
  $ make bar.o
```

it will use the second rule.

Now suppose you have TWO files `foo.c` and `foo.cpp`

Here make has to make a choice as to which takes precedence.  Make uses suffixes of files intimately for its build rules. What is considered a suffix is controlled by the `.SUFFIXES` directive.

The `.SUFFIXES` directive has a default built-in value that defines common suffixes such as .c .cpp .cc .o etc. in a particular order. If we want to change the order of precedence we clear that out with a blank line in Makefile i.e.:

```
.SUFFIXES:
```

and then follow it with our definition:

```
.SUFFIXES: .cpp .c .o
```

if you don't blank the line out, then make just appends the listed suffixes to its current list, that way multiple makefiles can simply add new suffixes without worrying about breaking each other.

Now since the .cpp is before .c the `.cpp.o` rule will take precedence (in case foo.cpp and foo.c are both present)

**NOTE**: Yes there is a "." before the words SUFFIXES and yes it is all capital letters.

Try to play with this Makefile to see the effects:

```
.SUFFIXES: 

.SUFFIXES:  .cpp .c .o


.c.o:
    echo Compiling C

.cpp.o:
    echo Compiling CPP
```

Make is very very powerful, and quite well documented so well worth the read. GNU make, which  is probably the strongest implementation with amazing extensions has made me a lot of money in the past :-) enjoy the experience.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I've read some Makefile tutorials this afternoon but your post cleared lots of my confusions. My makefile works perfect now. I guess I will use it a lot in the future :-)

Comment: Aha, your rules didn't work because .cu isn't in the list of default SUFFIXES. If you use implicit rules instead, that won't be a problem.

Comment: @blushift i think you mean *pattern rules* as opposed *suffix rules* which is what my example shows. implicit rules are actually mostly defined as suffix rules in most make implementations including GNU make.  Having said that, using pattern rules is definitely more powerful. Since we are confining ourselves to GNU make for the sake of this discussion, check out http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules

Answer (score 2):

Your rule is wrong, you want something like this:

```
%.o : %.cu
    $(NVCC) $(CCFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

That's assuming the command line you need to execute is something like

```
nvcc foo.cu -o foo.o
```

Otherwise, edit to suit.

Comment: a few typos... :-) $(NVCC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

Comment: Thanks, I guess that solved my problem. I don't know why for .cpp files, the rule is right. But for .cu files, the rule is wrong. Just point me to some article which can explain the detail would you? thanks very much!

Comment: Actually your .cpp rule is wrong too - but it's working for .cpp files by luck since make has a built-in default rule for .cpp files.
For reference look no further than the (GNU) make manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: @Ahmed: I don't know what typo you think I made. Looks good to me.

Comment: Actually, I have hacked around with make a lot, but never run into old-style suffix rules which I realised now is what you were using. My example uses (more common) implicit rules. I learned something!